# Eigenvector for rank one matrix $\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^{\top}$ disagrees with statistical software

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a matrix $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{xx}^{\top}$. Then it has one non-zero eigenvalue (since it is rank $1$) which is $\lambda \triangleq \mathbf{x}^{\top} \mathbf{x}$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{M x} \mathbf{x} &= \mathbf{x x}^{\top} \mathbf{x}
\\
&= \mathbf{x}^{\top} \mathbf{x x}
\\
&= \lambda \mathbf{x}.
\end{aligned}
$$

This also immediately implies that the eigenvector associated with $\lambda$ is simply $\mathbf{x}$ or any scaled version of $\mathbf{x}$, say $c \mathbf{x}$ for $c \neq 0$, since we could propagate $c$ thru the calculations. However, when I try this with statistical software, I get that my calculation for $\lambda$ is correct but not for the eigenvector.

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> M = np.outer(x, x)
>>> np.dot(x, x)
30
>>> vals, vecs = np.linalg.eig(M)
>>> vals[1]
29.999999999999993
>>> x / np.linalg.norm(x)
array([0.18257419, 0.36514837, 0.54772256, 0.73029674])
>>> vecs[1] / np.linalg.norm(vecs[1])
array([ 0.11528971, -0.62085412, -0.66034186, -0.40644443])
```

This may be a statistical computing question, but I'm asking here in case I'm misunderstanding something about the possible constraints on the eigenvector $c \mathbf{x}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `vecs[:,1]` instead of `vecs[1]`.

`vecs` is the matrix whose columns are eigenvectors, but you've accidentally selected a row of this matrix instead of a column.